# opening via socks

Tags: networking, socks

i have this socks : 80.176.245.196:1080 and i want to opening google.com via that socks . 
what am i going to do ? 
is this true ? : 80.176.245.196:1080/google.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy server, then you need to establish a socket connection to the proxy first, then send it a request telling it where to connect next (in this case, to google.com:80), and if successful then you can send normal HTTP requests to google directly using that same socket connection.  How to send a request to the SOCKS proxy depends on which version of SOCKS the proxy is actually using - [v4](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/socks/socks4/SOCKS4.protocol), [v4a](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Socks_4a) or [v5](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).